# How can I prevent this div in my table from increasing the cell height?

Tags: html, css

I have an example of the problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/s6t3p/

I have the following markup:

```
<h1>Just Text</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='cell'>Some Text</td>
        <td class='cell'>More Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<h1>With Icon Cell</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='cell'>Some Text</td>
        <td class='cell-ico'><div class='ico'></div></td>
        <td class='cell'>More Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the following CSS:

```
table,td,tr
{   
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border: none; outline: none;
    font-size: 100%; font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

table  { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
.cell 
{
    border:solid 1px #DDD; padding:0 5px; text-align:left;
    line-height:27px;
}
.ico {width:24px; height:24px; background:#05F;}
```

I wish for each cell to be 27px in height. This is the case for the 1st table. But the second table which contains a cell with a 24px div has a height of 32px. I don't understand why. It seems like a 24x24 div should fit inside fine without increasing the cell height.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it so that I can keep the cells at a height of 27px? I am currently testing with FireFox 29.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are doing a layout? Remember Tables are used for [tabular data](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html).

Comment: Yeah, please don't use tables for layouts. A puppy dies on every page load that way.

Comment: what your trying to achieve, make the height of div same as table cell or centering the div...??

Comment: Why is everyone thinking that he is trying to make a layout? I see nothing here that says that?!

Comment: Yeah, the real data is a tabular list of records. I'm not using a table because I like the way it lays out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are looking to display *tabular data*, then this is the way to go :)**

The behaviour is caused by  `vertical-align: baseline;`.

Just reset the `vertical-align` for `.cell-ico` and provide a set height. Give `.ico` a height of 100%.

[Have a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6t3p/4/)

```
.cell-ico {
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.ico {
    width:24px;
    height: 100%;
    background:#05F;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use div elements with their respective display attributes set to either `table`, `table-row,` `table-cell`, etc. Instead of actual tables. The use of tables as a layout techique [**is discouraged since HTML4**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). This approach may be a little bulky, but for layout purposes it'll save you some trouble dealing with css.

Check [**this jsfiddle for example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yrg5X/2/):

**HTML**:

```
<div id="Table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="Table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell2"><div class="oddDiv">im inside a div</div></div>
        <div class="cell2">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell2">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="cell2">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#Table {
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 27px;
}

.cell2 {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 24px;
}

.oddDiv {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Update, regarding semantics**:

It's true that from a developer's point of view there's no difference between a table markup element and a generic container like a div with the appearance of a table in terms of layout and even code comprehension. But, there's no way for an accessibility tool, say, an screen reader, to discern between a bunch of div elements with different id's, unless the tool was proprietary or there was some kind of convention for special id's to use for this kind of purposes (which I doubt). So for layout purposes divs are the way to go, but if semantics are a concern, the use of tables is the best solution.

Comment: From a purely semantic point of view, tabular data should be in a `<table>`. Tables have some quirks, but some basic CSS can get them under control and they can be beautiful :)

Comment: @misterManSam Please do not encourage the use of tables! That's an outmoded standard. Regarding layout, whatever you can do with `<table>`s, you can do better with `<div>`s.

Comment: Hence why I said: ***tabular data should be in a `<table>`***. Relax :)

Comment: The data really is a tabular list of records, so I agree with misterManSam. Though I'm curious what 'trouble' I'd avoid by making divs render as components of a table? By doing that you lose the benefits of a block element like having access to box-shadow. What do you gain?

Comment: That'd the same reasoning of saying that *centered text should be inside `center` tags*, but you don't do that now, right?. The `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell` properties **were also made for tabular data**. There's no diference between using a div and a table, only that the div is better supported by browsers and webkits. Tables are **outdated**.

Comment: @user3676163 no, you don't lose anything, in fact, you can achieve with them **everything** that you can with any normal div **plus** table-specific features (like vertical align, and such). Browsers in fact convert your tables to divs before rendering them, so they're really working double to get your table displayed if you use `<table>`. [**Also check this**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) and you'll see that many table properties aren't even supported on HTML5.

Comment: Those properties are largely obsolete due to CSS. Semantically, the `<table>` element should be used to display *tabular data*. `<table>` is fully supported in the HTML5 spec and there is no reason that will change. Could you provide a source on "Browsers in fact convert your tables to divs before rendering them"?

Comment: "That'd the same reasoning of saying that centered text should be inside center tags". The `<center>` tag is obsolete because it is semantically meaningless and was used for layout. The only use of HTML tags are to provide a semantic structure to your document and that is what a `<table>` does.

Comment: *"…provide a semantic structure…"*. So do `div` elements, plus they also work well for layout purposes. Also, what is the problem with using a **much better solution** for **tabular data** than tables are? I mean, they work just like old tables do plus they have better support for css, future webkits and they're more efficient.

Comment: @arielnmz You can't seriously think a div is as semantic as a table. That's ridiculous. A div is as semantic as a span which is to say really not at all. And maybe I'm just thick, but I don't see that you've said exactly why divs are so much better. Just that they can have the same layout and are somehow newer than  tables. Though div elements aren't exactly new either :) I suppose the CSS display option is :)

Comment: @user3676163 Yes, `<div>` and `<span>` indeed have **no semantic meaning** *per se*, but you completely forget the use of the `id` and `class` properties, other than for just layout purposes. What is then the difference between a `<quote>` and a `<div class="quote">`, for example? quote has a semantic meaning just for being a quote, whilst the class "quote" gives the generic container div a semantic meaning because that's what you want it to be. But anyway, assuming divs have no semantic meaning regardless of any other attributes, what could be the problem with that?

Comment: I think you are mistaken. Classes and ids have no semantic meaning to software, only to a human developer. The point of semantic markup is to use tags that software can interpret for users who for example are blind. They don't know what your CSS settings look like. But their browsing software may be able to make intelligent decisions about the data if it knows what the semantic meaning of the content is. But such software doesn't pay attention to CSS classes.

Comment: You have it right with that. Just at this moment I'm reading about semantics and how they're related to accessibility tools. It's true for a developer's point of view that there's no difference between markup and an id in terms of how to understand the code, but unless the tool is proprietary or there's an standard for special reserved id's (which I doubt) it's true that indeed there's no way a machine can discern between the use of one div and another even if they had their own different id's. But in your case, I think your original issue was more related to layout rather than semantics.

Comment: Another problem I've ran into with divs is there's no way to do a true colspan.

Comment: If for true you mean *by having an specific property to do so*, yes, there's no *true* way. And yes, the other solutions are kind of bulky for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this inside your CSS

```
td{
   vertical-align:middle;
   height:27px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like vertical-align: baseline; applied to all tags table, tr, td is messing it up.
Remove it and try it out.